# Apply slicing to array valued function in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, slice

can I apply slicing to the result of a vector valued function in Fortran without first assigning the result to a variable? E.g.:

```
    a = [1._dp, 2._dp, 3._dp]
    b = [5._dp, 2._dp, 2._dp]

    c = cross(a,b)  ! returns the vector product

    d = sum(c(1:2))

    d = sum(cross(a,b)(1:2))
```

Comment: so far the only solution I've found is:
`c = sum( reshape(cross(a,b),[2]) )`

Comment: No. Or, you can use the associate construct, but that is not much different.

Comment: And I find the intention clearer when a variable is used than with the reshape.